# priority_queue second parameter :Container object

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I know the  second parameter of priority_queue is a container(by default it's a `vector`). But what if I want to use `queue` or `list` as the underlying container?

```
struct compare {
    bool operator()(int&a,int&b) {
        return a > b;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::priority_queue<int, queue<int> , compare >pq();
    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't work when I use `pq.push()`.
So must `priority_queue` use `vector` as a container? Or how can I use queue instead?

I'd appreciate your help very much. Thanx a lot.

Comment: A queue is not a container. It is also an adaptor and uses a deque by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

> ***Container*** - The type of the underlying container to use to store the elements. The
>   container must satisfy the requirements of **[SequenceContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer)**  and its iterators must satisfy the requirements of RandomAccessIterator.
>   Additionally, it must provide the following functions with the usual
>   semantics:
>
> - front()
> - push_back()
> - pop_back()
>
> The standard containers **std::vector** and **std::deque** satisfy these
>   requirements.